# How to add custom classes and their variables/methods to Visual Studio Intellisense?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, visual-studio-2017

please excuse if this questions reveals some greater misunderstanding of Visual Studio and programming on my side.

I started to code Python using Visual Studio 2017. I have a file myclasses.py where I define new classes, e. g.

```
class myclass(object):
    def __init__(self, property):
        self.property = property
```

Into another file I import the file with the classes using

```
from myclasses import *
```

As with other python classes it would help me seeing which variables or methods I defined for class while typing using Intellisense, i. e. like it will suggest "accumulate" and "BuiltInImporter" after typing "itertools.", I would like to see "property" suggested to me after typing e. g.

```
classinstance = myclass("someproperty")
classinstance.
```

Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks a lot in advance!
Mike

Comment: I'm having trouble with getting intelisence to find things from modules I wrote too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meanwhile found my mistake: I had not yet specified the return statement of the method I used to generate the classinstance object, i. e. my code was

```
def GetInstance(property):
    newclassinstance = myclass(property)

classinstance = GetInstance("SomeProperty")
```

Which when typing classinstance. will not suggest anything as PTVS can't know that classinstance is of type myclass until I add

```
return newclassinstance
```

to the GetInstance method.